# Carousel with absolutely positioned children not working

Tags: html, css, css-position, carousel, absolute

I'm building a carousel with HTML/CSS and have a problem I can't get my head around.

I have absolutely positioned children (.card) in a carousel-container and want them to slide from side to side when clicking the links below. This works fine when going from card4 backwards to card1, but not forwards from card1 to card4. Then it just jumps to card4 and seems to push the active card off the screen.

Strangely, when I edit my non-active cards' position to

```
left:95%;
```

instead of

```
left:100%;
```

(see at the very bottom of the CSS snippet), it works as expected.

Tested in Chrome, Firefox and on Codepen
[View on CodePen](https://codepen.io/RainbowFlower/pen/jXNoEw)

Thank you very much for your help.

This is my code:

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.carousel-links{
  text-align:center;
  position:fixed;
  bottom: 5%;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  z-index:100;
}
.carousel-links a{
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1em;
  background:white;
}


.carousel{
  position: relative;
  width:100%;
  height:80vh;
  background:yellow;
  border:5px solid black;
  display:block;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.card{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:-100%;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  border: 1px dashed black;
  font-size:100px;
  transition: all 2s;
  z-index:1;
}
.carousel > .card:target{
  left:0%;
  //background:rgba(255,0,0,1);
  z-index:2;
}
.carousel > .card:target~*{
  left:100%; 
  /* left:95%;  /*with this line it works */
  z-index:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-links">
  <a href="#card1">1</a>
  <a href="#card2">2</a>
  <a href="#card3">3</a>
  <a href="#card4">4</a>
</div>

<div class="carousel">
  <div class="card" id="card1">1</div>
  <div class="card" id="card2">2</div>
  <div class="card" id="card3">3</div>
  <div class="card" id="card4">4</div>
</div>
```